# CloudKit Dashboard shows push log, but it is not received, why?

Tags: push-notification, apple-push-notifications, cloudkit

I am struggling since a couple of weeks with the implementation of a silent push notification  of database changes from iCloud. I have read everything about that, but I couldn't find out what I am missing to finally receive the push notification. Now I watched the loggings on CloudKit Dashboard and I surprisingly found, that there is a "push" logging (see image below).

[image: Partial screenshot from CloudKit Dashboard]

But my real devices (iPhone and iPad) are never receiving the push notification via "application didReceive...." in the AppDelegate? What could be the reason. YES, I registered successfully for push notification in "application didFinishLaunching" and the apps capabilities are set properly. Does the logging prove a push from APNS ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At the end the solution was to activate a "reset" on the CloudKit Dashboards development environment. No more problems after that. What a relief, it is "pushing" nicely and completely as expected.

[image]